# Trouble parsing JSON Google Place data

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a rating on a place from google. I'm doing a JSON request by placeID, requesting the fields name and rating. When i view the JSON url in my browser, I see the following data:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "Coffeetots Play Café",
      "rating" : 4.7
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I'm getting stuck when trying to save the "rating" field as a variable in javascript/jQuery, or display it on the page. My code is below (removed my API key), I'm assuming I don't need an 'each' loop because there is only one place, but I haven't found any other way to do it.

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJgRUw-0_dekgRWCHhui-rPBg&fields=name,rating&key=XXX", function(json){
  $.each(json.results, function(i, place){
    myRating = place.rating;
    $("#results").append('<p>'+myRating+'</p>');
  });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Assuming your example is correct, then all you need is  `$("#results").append('<p>'+ json.result.rating+'</p>');` - i.e. no each

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is there an error? Just to be clear, you did replace the `each()` loop with that line, right?

Comment: Have tried with and without the each loop.

Here's a ;link to the codepen

https://codepen.io/fraig/pen/wNBYPm?editors=1000

Comment: Your pen does not work, The call does not work due to CORS issues and jQuery placement

Comment: You should **restrict your API key** before using it / posting it as clear text anywhere otherwise you might have some bad surprises...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `json.result` instead of `json.results` as per the JSON you provided in the question.

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "Coffeetots Play Café",
      "rating" : 4.7
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the example results, you get an array that does not look like your example.

This works using the google example found here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

```js
var json = {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.867217,
               "lng" : 151.195939
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "7eaf747a3f6dc078868cd65efc8d3bc62fff77d7",
         "name" : "Biaggio Cafe - Pyrmont",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 600,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAmWmj0BqA0Jorm1_vjAvx1n6c7ZNBxyY-U9x99-oNyOxvMjDlo2npJzyIq7c3EK1YyoNXdMFDcRPzwLJtBzXAwCUFDGo_RtLRGBPJTA2CoerPdC5yvT2SjfDwH4bFf5MrznB0_YWa4Y2Qo7ABtAxgeBIQv46sGBwVNJQDI36Wd3PFYBoUTlVXa0wn-zRITjGp0zLEBh8oIBE",
               "width" : 900
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJIfBAsjeuEmsRdgu9Pl1Ps48",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "rating" : 3.4,
         "reference" : "CoQBeAAAAGu0wNJjuZ40DMrRe3mpn7fhlfIK1mf_ce5hgkhfM79u-lqy0G2mnmcueTq2JGWu9wsgS1ctZDHTY_pcqFFJyQNV2P-kdhoRIeYRHeDfbWtIwr3RgFf2zzFBXHgNjSq-PSzX_OU6OT2_3dzdhhpV-bPezomtrarW4DsGl9uh773yEhDJT6R3V8Fyvl_xeE761DTCGhT1jJ3floFI5_c-bHgGLVwH1g-cbQ",
         "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.866786,
               "lng" : 151.195633
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3ef986cd56bb3408bc1cf394f3dad9657c1d30f6",
         "name" : "Doltone House",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1260,
               "html_attributions" : [ "From a Google User" ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRwAAAAeM-aLqAm573T44qnNe8bGMkr_BOh1MOVQaA9CCggqtTwuGD1rjsviMyueX_G4-mabgH41Vpr8L27sh-VfZZ8TNCI4FyBiGk0P4fPxjb5Z1LrBZScYzM1glRxR-YjeHd2PWVEqB9cKZB349QqQveJLRIQYKq2PNlOM0toJocR5b_oYRoUYIipdBjMfdUyJN4MZUmhCsTMQwg",
               "width" : 1890
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ5xQ7szeuEmsRs6Kj7YFZE9k",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAA22k1PAGyDxAgHZk6ErHh_h_mLUK_8XNFLvixPJHXRbCzg-gw1ZxdqUwA_8EseDuEZKolBs82orIQH4m6-afDZV9VcpggokHD9x7HdMi9TnJDmGb9Bdh8f-Od4DK0fASNBL7Me3CsAWkUMWhlNQNYExIQ05W7VbxDTQe2Kh9TiL840hoUZfiO0q2HgDHSUyRdvTQx5Rs2SBU",
         "types" : [ "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}

 $.each(json.results, function(i, place){
    myRating = place.rating || "not rated"
    $("#results").append('<p>'+i+':'+' '+place.name+' '+myRating+'</p>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

If you call by ID you get this back according to https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id

```js
var json =     {
      "html_attributions" : [],
      "results" : [
        {
          "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
              "lat" : -33.870775,
              "lng" : 151.199025
            }
          },
          "place_id" : "ChIJrTLr-GyuEmsRBfy61i59si0",
          "name": "Somewhere",
          "rating": 4.5
        }
      ],
      "status" : "OK"
    }


 $.each(json.results, function(i, place){
    myRating = place.rating || "not rated"
    $("#results").append('<p>'+i+':'+' '+place.name+' '+myRating+'</p>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

If you truly get the object back you show, then you cannot use each:

```js
var json =    {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "name" : "Coffeetots Play Café",
      "rating" : 4.7
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}


 myRating = json.result.rating || "not rated";
 $("#results").append('<p>'+json.result.name+' '+myRating+'</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not help me. That documentation is for place search - I know the place, I just want to call it by ID, and return the place name and place rating.

Comment: So please show a complete result - you call it results which seems it is an array, but you show an object.

Comment: This is where it is beyond my knowledge, which is why I am here!

When calling the JSON file, the data I get back is what I have put in the OP.

Comment: According to my investigation you get an array back in results `"results" : [`  but you have an object. See my second example

Comment: See my 3rd example based on your object.

Comment: Thanks, that (your third point) works when putting the JSON in the JS file, but not when I use the $.getJSON method, which is what I need to do. Sorry, I have no experience with JSON requests. As far as I know, there are no problems with my API key.

Comment: Please console.log(json)